# Are my debug statements correct? Is the class being used correctly? I am not currently getting errors but also am getting no output

Tags: c#, file, class, average

I am tasked to write a program that accesses an outside text file that contains basketball player names and scores. I have always had issues reading and writing from txt files regardless of language. Once the txt file is read from, the program is supposed to output the average scores for all players as well as the player name of the highest scorer. I am getting several errors thrown from my code which won't run. Are my debug statements correct? Is the class being used correctly? Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BasketBallScore
{
public partial class BasketballStats : Form
{

    private string score;

    public BasketballStats()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class BasketballController
    {
        public class Entry
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        BasketballController(string filename)
        {
            this.filename = filename;
        }
        private string filename;
        private List<Entry> data = new List<Entry>();
        public List<Entry> Data
        {
            get
            {
                // Clear data
                data.Clear();
                // Iterate through lines
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
                {
                    // Split by space
                    List<string> parts = line.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
                    if (parts.Count() < 2)
                        continue;
                    // Number is last space separated string
                    int number = int.Parse(parts.Last());
                    // Remove number
                    parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count() - 1);
                    // Name is any previous word joined by space
                    string name = string.Join(" ", parts).Trim();

                    // Add number and name to data
                    data.Add(new Entry() { Name = name, Value = number });
                }
                // Sort from greater value to smaller
                data.Sort(Comparer<Entry>.Create(
                    (l, r) => r.Value.CompareTo(l.Value)));
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
                {
                    foreach (var entry in value)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", entry.Name, entry.Value));
                    }
                }
                data = value;
            }
        }
        public double Average
        {
            get
            {
                // Read file if data is empty, otherwise reuse its value
                var src = (data.Count() == 0) ? Data : data;
                if (src.Count() == 0)
                    return 0.0;
                // Return average
                return src.Average(x => x.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BtnCreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        score = "basketBallScore.txt";
        if (File.Exists(score))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileName: {0}", score);
            Console.WriteLine("Attributes: {0}",
                File.GetAttributes(score));
            Console.WriteLine("Created: {0}",
                File.GetCreationTime(score));
            Console.WriteLine("Last Accessed: {0}",
                File.GetLastAccessTime(score));

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".");
            Console.WriteLine("Current Directory: \n{0} \n",
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            Console.WriteLine("File Name".PadRight(52) +
                "Size".PadRight(10) + "Creation Time");
            foreach (FileInfo fil in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
            {
                string name = fil.Name;
                long size = fil.Length;
                DateTime creationTime = fil.CreationTime;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1,12:NO} {2, 20:g} ", name.PadRight(45),
                    size, creationTime);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} not found - using current" +
                "directory:", score);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private void CalcAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = new BasketballController("basketBallScore.txt");
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Average {0}", c.Average));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("First {0} {1}", c.Data.First().Name, c.Data.First().Value));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Last {0} {1}", c.Data.Last().Name, c.Data.Last().Value));
    }
}
```

}

This is what the text file contains:

```
Lebron James        31
Steph Curry         12
Kyrie Irving        37
Kevin Durant        9
Paul George         35
Klay Thompson       8
J.R.Smith           12  
Zaza Pachulia       4
Tristan Thompson    10
Draymond Green      2
```

The program will access the file but will not give any output beyond the verification of the the data file. This is an updated version of a previous program. This was what I had previously:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TextFiles
{
public partial class BasketBallStats : Form
{
    List<int> marks = new List<int>();

public BasketBallStats()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

// Form load event handler used to construct
// object of the Streamwriter class, sending the 
// new filename as an argument. Enclosed in
// try...catch block.
public class BasketballController
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    BasketballController(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    private string filename;
    private List<Entry> data = new List<Entry>();
    public List<Entry> Data
    {
        get
        {
            // Clear data
            data.Clear();
            // Iterate through lines
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
            {
                // Split by space
                List<string> parts = line.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
                if (parts.Count() < 2)
                    continue;
                // Number is last space separated string
                int number = int.Parse(parts.Last());
                // Remove number
                parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count() - 1);
                // Name is any previous word joined by space
                string name = string.Join(" ", parts).Trim();

                // Add number and name to data
                data.Add(new Entry() { Name = name, Value = number });
            }
            // Sort from greater value to smaller
            data.Sort(Comparer<Entry>.Create(
                (l, r) => r.Value.CompareTo(l.Value)));
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                foreach (var entry in value)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", entry.Name, entry.Value));
                }
            }
            data = value;
        }
    }
    public double Average
    {
        get
        {
            // Read file if data is empty, otherwise reuse its value
            var src = (data.Count() == 0) ? Data : data;
            if (src.Count() == 0)
                return 0.0;
            // Return average
            return src.Average(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
}

private string score;

public List<int> Marks { get => Marks1; set => Marks1 = value; }
public List<int> Marks1 { get => marks; set => marks = value; }

private void BasketBallStats_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void BtnCreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    score = "basketBallScore.txt";
    if (File.Exists(score))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FileName: {0}", score);
        Console.WriteLine("Attributes: {0}",
            File.GetAttributes(score));
        Console.WriteLine("Created: {0}",
            File.GetCreationTime(score));
        Console.WriteLine("Last Accessed: {0}",
            File.GetLastAccessTime(score));

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".");
        Console.WriteLine("Current Directory: \n{0} \n",
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        Console.WriteLine("File Name".PadRight(52) +
            "Size".PadRight(10) + "Creation Time");
        foreach (FileInfo fil in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
        {
            string name = fil.Name;
            long size = fil.Length;
            DateTime creationTime = fil.CreationTime;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1,12:NO} {2, 20:g} ", name.PadRight(45),
                size, creationTime);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} not found - using current" +
            "directory:", score);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private void BtnWriteFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var WriteToFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("basketBallScore.txt"); //create textfile in default directory
        WriteToFile.Write(listView1.Text + ", " + listView1.Text + ", " + listView1.Text + ", " + listView1.Text);
        WriteToFile.Close();
        Marks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Text)); //add to list
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "File did not close properly: ";    //add error message
    }
}

private void ManipulateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] hoursArray = new int[30];
    StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("basketBallScore.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    string line = "";
    line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        hoursArray[counter] = int.Parse(line);
        counter = counter + 1;
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    }
    fileSR.Close();

    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
    {
        total = total + hoursArray[index];
    }
    average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;

    int high = hoursArray[0];
    for (int index = 1; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
    {
        if (hoursArray[index] > high)
        {
            high = hoursArray[index];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Highest number is: " + high);
    Console.WriteLine("The average is: " + average);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void BasketBallStats_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void CalcAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totalmarks = 0;
    foreach (int m in Marks)
        totalmarks += m;

    MessageBox.Show("Average Is: " + totalmarks / Marks.Count);
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = new BasketballController("basketBallScore.txt");
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Average {0}", c.Average));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("First {0} {1}", c.Data.First().Name, c.Data.First().Value));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Last {0} {1}", c.Data.Last().Name, c.Data.Last().Value));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a _specific_ question? Or were you just hoping someone would do the work for you? Please explain _precisely_ what the code you have now does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: I do not hope someone would do work for me. My question is in the title thank you very much. I am very stuck and am not sure what to do. I was getting an error in the calculate average button with the BasketBallController method but I added public to the constructor so it could be accessed. I had a totally different program before but have changed it up considerably with some suggestions, I just really need help.

Comment: _"My question is in the title"_ -- I know. I saw it before. That's not a real question, as it's not _specific_. _"I just really need help"_ -- then I recommend you edit your question so that is clear enough to answer without just writing the whole program over again for you. (By the way, you should avoid property getters with side-effects; that is, the `Data` property shouldn't be where you read the data. Put the initialization code into an `Initialize()` method, or a factory method, or even the constructor would be better than a property getter.)

Comment: The property getter was suggested to me by someone on this site.

Comment: _"The property getter was suggested to me by someone on this site"_ -- don't believe everything you read on the Internet. Suffice to say, the person who suggested that to you is giving you bad advice, especially if they also advised you to use the property that way (i.e. to _always_ repopulate the list on the `get` method, and to check the state of the data list before calling the `Data` getter).

Comment: Please do not clutter your question with the old code. The only thing that matters is the attempt to improve upon the _current_ code. Also, you write: _"I am getting several errors thrown from my code"_. Your question (which is still not stated in any sort of specific way) needs to include _detailed_ information about errors. The _exact_ text of any error or exception message, the exact name of any exception thrown, and the full stack trace for any exception thrown.

Comment: Rather than lecture me could you please help me. I have posted at least questions: Are my debug statements correct? Is the class being used correctly? Currently the old code is working better than the newer code.

Comment: Adding debug statements isn't always the best method for debugging.  The debug statements could add errors to the code or not display anything.  The first attempt to debug code should be to add break points by clicking on a line of code and then pressing F9.  The run code until break point is reached (either run of F5).  Then you can step through code using F11.  So you should see which sections of the code you are reaching and not reaching.  Also you can hover over variables when stopped to see the value of the variables.  You can also right click on the variables and select add to watch.

Comment: I was not aware of the debug statements before this project. They were suggested so that is why I have them included. I have tried other statements previously but am open to suggestions as I am stuck and cannot get the program to give me the correct output statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to code a program that does exactly what I needed it to do. Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace BasketballScores
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnOutputData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = "basketBallScore.txt";
            var c = new BasketballPlayer(path);
            ListView1.Items.Add(string.Format("\r\nAverage {0}", c.Average));
            ListView1.Items.Add(string.Format("\r\nFirst {0} {1}", c.Data.First().Name, c.Data.First().Value));
            ListView1.Items.Add(string.Format("\r\nLast {0} {1}", c.Data.Last().Name, c.Data.Last().Value));
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.Text);
                    for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }        
  }
}
```

This is a class I have with the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasketballScores
{
class BasketballPlayer
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
public BasketballPlayer(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    private string filename;
    private List<Entry> data = new List<Entry>();
    public List<Entry> Data
    {
        get
        {
            // Clear data
            data.Clear();
            // Iterate through lines
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
            {
                // Split by space
                List<string> parts = line.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
                if (parts.Count() < 2)
                    continue;
                // Number is last space separated string
                int number = int.Parse(parts.Last());
                // Remove number
                parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count() - 1);
                // Name is any previous word joined by space
                string name = string.Join(" ", parts).Trim();

                // Add number and name to data
                data.Add(new Entry() { Name = name, Value = number });
            }
            // Sort from greater value to smaller
            data.Sort(Comparer<Entry>.Create(
                (l, r) => r.Value.CompareTo(l.Value)));
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                foreach (var entry in value)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", entry.Name, entry.Value));
                }
            }
            data = value;
        }
    }
    public double Average
    {
        get
        {
            // Read file if data is empty, otherwise reuse its value
            var src = (data.Count() == 0) ? Data : data;
            if (src.Count() == 0)
                return 0.0;
            // Return average
            return src.Average(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
  }
}
```